# On alternating sums of the elements of subsets.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math

Recently in a contest a question was asked as under.

We define a lead element of a set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3, \cdots a_n\}$ as $$l(\{a_1,a_2,a_3, \cdots a_n\})=|a_1-a_2+a_3-a_4 \cdots(-1)^{n-1}a_n|$$

Now let  $X_n$ be the set of natural numbers from $1$ to $n$.

> Then find the sum of all the lead elements of all the non empty subsets of $X_n$ in terms of $n$?

I guess some recursion relation will build up ,but I am not able to get the solution.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the first few terms, finding a pattern, then trying to prove it by induction?

Comment: what do you use for the ordering of elements needed to define the lead elements of a subset?

Comment: The same order of 1 to n

Comment: So its not a set, its an ordered sequence is it? If so, you could group the difference of adjacent elements together and see what happens for even and odd $n$ separately

Comment: @Macavity kinda ..but the question used the word set

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by your comment that $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_k$.

If $k$ is even,
$$\begin{aligned}
l(\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_k\}) &= |a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots-a_k|\\
&= |\underbrace{(a_1-a_2)}_{\le 0}+\underbrace{(a_3-a_4)}_{\le 0}+\dots+\underbrace{(a_{k-1}-a_k)}_{\le 0}|\\
&= -a_1+a_2-a_3+\dots+a_k
\end{aligned}$$

If $k$ is odd,
$$\begin{aligned}
l(\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_k\}) &= |a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots+a_k|\\
&= |a_1+\underbrace{(a_3-a_2)}_{\ge 0}+\dots+\underbrace{(a_k-a_{k-1})}_{\ge 0}|\\
&= a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots+a_k
\end{aligned}$$

As consequence, we get $l(A)+l(A\cup\{n\}) = n$ for $A\subset X_{n-1}$.

Therefore
$$\sum_{A\subset X_{n}} l(A) = \sum_{A\subset X_{n-1}} l(A)+l(A\cup\{n\}) = \sum_{A\subset X_{n-1}} n = 2^{n-1}n$$